# How to detect 4G dongle(s) connected to my computer using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, network-programming, usb, dongle

How can I detect 4G dongle(s) connected to my computer using NodeJS?

I tried the following code:

```
var os = require('os');
var allNetworkInterfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
console.log(allNetworkInterfaces);
```

It works, but I got all network interfaces... I would like to get a list with my 4G dongles only. Knowing that I could have either 1 dongle, or several dongles connected to the same computer, as well as other USB hardwares connected.

Comment: this library might help https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb

Answer (score 0):

After installing the `usb` package by running `npm install usb` I was able to get a list of usb devices using the following code:

```
const usb = require('usb');
const devices = usb.getDeviceList();
console.log( devices );
```

You will have to go through that list and decide which is your "4G dongle".